# serverInputStream cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, tcp, compression

For a project, I have to code a multi-threaded client-server implementation of a 
message service using encryption and compression. I am coding the run method in the server file  and encounter errors when I get to the following lines:

`CompressedMessage compmsg = (CompressedMessage)serverInputStream.readObject();` - here I get an error under the `serverInputStream` with the message

> serverInputStream cannot be resolved

and under every `fromClient` with the message

> fromClient cannot be resolved

Can anyone explain what is causing these errors and how to resolve them?
Here is the part of the program

```
    public void run()
    {   try
        {   //send greeting to this client
            threadOutputStream.writeObject(getCompressedMessage("Welcome to the chat server " + clientName));
            // inform this client of other clients online
            threadOutputStream.writeObject(getCompressedMessage("online" + getChatClients()));
            // output to server window
            addOutput(clientName + " known as " + chatName + " has joined");
            // inform other clients that this client has joined
            sendMessage("join" + chatName);

            boolean quit = false, broadcast = false;
            // this loop will continue until the client quits the chat service
            while(!quit)
            {   // read next compressed message from client
                CompressedMessage compmsg = (CompressedMessage)serverInputStream.readObject();
                // decompress message
                compmsg.decompress();
                // retrieve decompressed message
                compmsg.getMessage();
                // find position of separating character
                int foundPos = fromClient.indexOf('#');
                // list of recipients for message
                String sendTo = fromClient.substring(0,foundPos);
                // message to be sent to recipients
                String message = fromClient.substring(foundPos+1);

                // if the message is "quit" then this client wishes to leave the chat service
                if(message.equals("quit"))
                {   // add message to server output area
                    addOutput(clientName + " has " + message);
                    // inform other clients that this client has quit
                    sendMessage("quit" + chatName);
                    //send "goodbye" message to this client
                    threadOutputStream.writeObject("Goodbye");
                    // remove this client from the list of clients
                    remove(chatName);
                }
                else
                {   // add message to server output area
                    addOutput(clientName + ">> " + message);
                    // split string to separate recipients names
                    String[] recipients = sendTo.split(",\\s*");
                    // sort this array to use binarySearch
                    Arrays.sort(recipients);
                    // identify if this message is to be sent to all other clients
                    foundPos = Arrays.binarySearch(recipients, chattag[chattag.length-1]);
                    if(foundPos >= 0)
                       // send this message to all other clients
                        sendMessage(chatName + ">> " + message);
                    else
                        // send this message to all clients in recipients array
                        sendMessage(chatName + ">> " + message, recipients);
                }
            } // end while

            // close input stream
            threadInputStream.close();
            // close output stream
            threadOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) // thrown by method readObject, writeObject, close
        {   System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) // thrown by method readObject
        {   System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

`serverInputStream` is declared in a method higher up the program called `void getClients()` like this `ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()); ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());` and from client isn't declared anywhere, it was in the skeleton code provided and only appears in that segment of code

Comment: Where is `serverInputStream` declared? Where is `fromClient` declared?

Comment: `serverInputStream` is declared in a method higher up the program called void `getClients()` like this `
       ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());` and `from client` isn't declared anywhere, it was in the skeleton code provided and only appears in that segment of code

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use variable any where in your code. The variable has to be in scope when you use it.

So if `serverInputStream` is declared in the method `getClients()`, it can only be used in that method. Consider declaring your variables in a larger scope, like member variables. Go through the [Java Classes and Objects tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about reading the next compressed message from the client file? Would I re-declare these variables in the `run()` class or use some other code to read it?

Comment: @user3080208 You will have to ask another question with the complete details if something is not working. First, figure out your variable scopes and use them appropriately.

Comment: By adding Socket 

client = serverSocket.accept(); 

          // get input & output streams
          ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
       ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

to the run method the error for the `serverInputStream` went away. I still don't understand what `fromClient` does or why there is an error. I'm a bit rusty on Java and have never used it in Eclipse or for networking before.

Comment: @user If you don't know what `fromClient` does, how are we supposed to know? We can explain why you get the errors, but not what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

A friend asked me to do this assignment for him as he couldn't figure how to get it working like you.

`fromClient` is the message which we retrieve after being decompressed.

```
// read next compressed message from client
CompressedMessage cm = (CompressedMessage) threadInputStream.readObject();

// decompress message
cm.decompress();

// retrieve decompressed message
String fromClient = cm.getMessage();
```

This is the lines of code I have used in his assignment.
Also do not use `serverInputStream` use `threadInputStream` which was declared here

```
private class Chat_ServerThread extends Thread
```